# Censor emails with PHP

Tags: php, email

I'm using this simple code:

```
$raw = 'text hi@li.com text';
$raw = preg_replace('<[\w.]+@[\w.]+>', '***@$2', $raw);
```

And i should get as output, something like `***@li.com`; while i get `***@`

I can't debug it, i don't know how what's wrong.

---

So the solution is

```
preg_replace('<([\w.]+)@([\w.]+)>', '***@$2', $raw);
```

I had to add () to make a group.

Comment: A censure ( /ˈsɛnʃər/) is an expression of strong disapproval or harsh criticism. Do you mean "censor"?

Comment: I believe you need to mark the matches you wish to later reference using $x with parenthesis, for example: `'<([\w.])+@([\w.])+>'` and then $2 will reference the second `([\w.])`

Comment: I've edit it. I'm not an english native, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to create a group by adding (), and BTW it's gonna be $1:

```
$raw = ' hi@li.com ';
$raw = preg_replace('/[^@]+@([^\s]+)/', '***@$1', $raw);
```

also modified .+ tp [^\s]+ so it "eats" only the email and not the text after it

Comment: I didn't know about (); this is the one that works for me (not your code, my code with (). Since that i'm using it for an email inside the text your code would grep everything, while preg_replace('<([\w.]+)@([\w.]+)>', '***@$2', $raw); works

Answer (score 3):

```
$raw = ' hi@li.com ';
$raw = preg_replace('/[^@]+@(.+)/', '***@$1', $raw);
```

Comment: @Mat Fixed that ... darn copy & paste.

Answer (score 1):

Here without regex:

```
$raw = 'hi@li.com';
$raw = explode('@', $raw);
array_shift($raw);
$raw = '***@'.implode('', $raw);
```

Comment: that will work only if $raw is only composed of an email; it's not, it's text with emails in it; thanks anyway

Comment: @cedivad in this case I'm not sure the other examples will work, 'cause if your text continues after the email address, the (.+) in the regular expression will continue 'till the end of the 1st line IMHO

Answer (score 0):

Regex is a little bit overkill for this task. Using the `explode()` function and a little bit of string concatenation would should be enough.

```
$pieces = explode('@', $raw);
$raw = '***@' . $raw[count($raw) - 1];
```

Notice, the way I'm accessing the domain part of the email address stored in `$raw`. I'm not using `$raw[1]` because the `@` character can actually be used as an email address (If it's surrounded by quotation marks), although it is a bit unusual actually. You can see some more example of email addresses here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in the question, i will next time so that people like you don't spend time for nothing for a fault of mine. $raw is composed of common text *and* emails, so exploding won't work. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively use the [strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) function. Also with the true param you can get the part before the needle and count the length and pad with asterix.

```
<?php
$email  = 'name@example.com';

$len = strlen(strstr($email, '@', true));
$domain = strstr($email, '@');

echo str_repeat('*',$len).$domain; // prints ****@example.com
?>
```